# Add panel with button click

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

It was my school homework and i bit confused with it
in my school homework i need to give some picture then count with condition (for example, if there 3 mammals so i must input 3 for the answer) then if it right it'll go to the next level and it'll add 1 for column and row. For example, for start it is 2x3 then for the next level it's 3x4

the thing that make me confused how i can add some panel for insert picture when i trigger something ? Then for every panel that'll added i want to give it array so i can use loop for set every panel.

note : this homework use java netbeans gui

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. If you ask for help with homework, post the code you wrote so far and and exact descriptions where you are stuck.

Answer (score 2):

> i can add some panel for insert picture when i trigger something ?

Don't add a JPanel.

When you design the GUI you can add a `JLabel` to your frame. Then when you want to change the image you just change the `Icon` of the label.

So your basic logic would be:

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(...);
label.setIcon( icon );
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Icon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) for more information and working examples that use Icons.

Comment: I would also suggest reading [How to use Action Listeners](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) to respond to events (i.e. Trigger something) like a clic on a button.